# how to improve AV recording quality in swift. i want HD recording

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

bellow is my current AVRecorder settings, I want to improve it to have the highest quality of the recording.

```
let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
                ]
```

Comment: max is the highest one , what the issue u faced

Comment: I dont feel that its HD Quality. I want HD Quality

Comment: It’s just a phone with a 2mm mic after all... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is still not so good as other recording apps.
i want to get the highest configuration for recording. 
sampleRateKey and AVFormatIDKey can it be still improved ?

Comment: sampleRateKey - already you used high,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks will check that

Comment: but ensure once your does not receive the memory warning

Comment: Using an external mic rather than the built in 2mm mic should produce the quality desired right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To improve AV Recording quality change formatIDKey : **kAudioFormatAppleLossless**

```
let settings = [
                        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
                        AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
               ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
// this effects the quality of video
session?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

you have more options to configure `AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset` property see image.

[image]

Comment: I want for Audio Recording and not for video. i am using
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

Comment: thanks i am using session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
cannot find sessionPreset in it. could you help me more ?

Comment: use `let session = AVCaptureSession?`.

Comment: i tried let session = AVAudioSession.init() but no method of sessionPreset in session yet !

Comment: you dont need `init()` just dec `let session = AVCaptureSession?` like.